# Creating Properties Dynamically in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dynamic, devextreme

I'm building a data entry application using the DataGrid from DevExpress (devextreme) and allowing users to add and remove columns aside from the key column.  I am storing both the column configuration and user data in SQL.  The user data is stored as

```
Key | ColumnName        | ColumnValue
-------------------------------------
1     Company             Apple
1     NumberOfEmployees   12345
```

I then pivot the data to send to the grid.

```
Key | Company | NumberOfEmployees
---------------------------------
1     Apple     12345
```

When a user updates a row in the grid, the grid passes back a data object with properties for each column.  I am using the column definition to try and find and match these properties back up but not getting the expected results.

```
const userColumns: any[] = [
    {
        ColumnName: 'Company'
    }, {
        ColumnName: 'NumberOfEmployees'
    }
];

const returnedFromGridRow: Record<string,any> = {};
returnedFromGridRow.Company = 'Apple';
returnedFromGridRow.NumberOfEmployees = 12345;

let result: Record<string,any> = {};
const results: any = [];

userColumns.forEach(function (value) {
  let x: string = value.ColumnName;
  let y: string = returnedFromGridRow[x];
  
  result = {x:y};
  console.log(result);
  results.push(result);
});
```

Expecting

```
{ "Company" : "Apple" }
{ "NumberOfEmployees" : 12345 }
```

but getting

```
{ "x" : "Apple" }
{ "x" : 12345 }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwMIgDZwLaQFwwCGYAngNoC6MAvDGQLABQMLMA3k61zOlrgHKFsiAgHJ02AA7ESozqwC%20AGnbzuPTDjCDhY-jgBGKAPIAzAKJSMIEokQQ5zRUwoBuJk1CRYyRFDjIYIgAJgBiyCDYAOLIAJbBAEogAO4ECYigyMEAPNBxYADmSjIAfDTsCu6Mvv6BIeGRMfFJyQB0EtKk5aIAgpKSGIiiVTUBQWER0XGJKa362EbIZpYDNnYQ5QCMAEwAzAAsAKxVTIM%209nAYUGkZIFm5UPlFpeVslZ7g0DC%20EJdQEAQZOVKCdGAgULwtBBWqY7uZCMAABYAClMcDAwCgsXAMGRADdCFhEABKVROM4wAAeBDysUK5QJRPamgEQkQVRYFJINMedIK5VGdQmjWmLTIlLc8nkPz%20r2pJHeTi8EEwiFa1gKyJlV2JHO%20Fyu0MkCBR2qguqYCgtjCAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using to create the `result` object won't work because it takes `x` as the key. To dynamically specify key, change the way you create the dynamic object like below to get the expected result:

```js
userColumns.forEach(function (value) {
  let x: string = value.ColumnName;
  let y: string = returnedFromGridRow[x];
  
  result[x]=y; // This is the change
  console.log(result);
  results.push(result);
});
```